# Why are my email notifications coming in as plain text?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification

Suddenly, starting yesterday, my email notifications from SE are coming in as plain text. It is nearly impossible to make sense of it.

```
The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2013-04-01: Apr, 1 What is the argument(s) that Jesus may have be gay or tending homosexual?
comment: @fredsbend it exists but it is hypothetical as well as not commensurate with what Jesus taught. A... Apr, 1 Why are the wicked resurrected only to be destroyed and sent to the Lake of Fire?
answer: I think the misunderstanding here is that the wicked are resurrected and then killed. I'm not su... Apr, 1 What is the Biblical basis to declare that ‘justice necessitates the resurrection of the body’?
comment: You are not really arguing for a biblical basis. That's how these questions work. I am aski... Apr, 1 Why are the wicked resurrected only to be destroyed and sent to the Lake of Fire?
comment: I don't know that this can possibly be constructive. You're asking for us to explain ...If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may unsubscribe from this email.
```

When this combined with word wrap I get something like this:

> The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2013-04-01: Apr, 1 What is the argument(s) that Jesus may have be gay or tending homosexual?
>   comment: @fredsbend it exists but it is hypothetical as well as not commensurate with what Jesus taught. A... Apr, 1 Why are the wicked resurrected only to be destroyed and sent to the Lake of Fire?
>   answer: I think the misunderstanding here is that the wicked are resurrected and then killed. I'm not su... Apr, 1 What is the Biblical basis to declare that ‘justice necessitates the resurrection of the body’?
>   comment: You are not really arguing for a biblical basis. That's how these questions work. I am aski... Apr, 1 Why are the wicked resurrected only to be destroyed and sent to the Lake of Fire?
>   comment: I don't know that this can possibly be constructive. You're asking for us to explain ...If you no longer wish to receive updates every 3 hours, you may unsubscribe from this email.

I would like to get the HTML emails back. I did not intentionally change a setting on my profile and i cannot find a setting to change it back if I did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was an issue with sanitizing html in our email code; a fix was pushed earlier today, so any new emails should be fine.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I will report back on the next notification I get.

Comment: Great support. The last two emails came in HTML. Thank you, Salty Sailor.